# Thymeleaf multiple submit button in one form

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a fragment of HTML page with one form and 2 button:

```html
<form action="#" data-th-action="@{/action/edit}" data-th-object="${model}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="save">save</button>
    <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel">cancel</button>
</form>
```

And the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute SomeModel model, 
        @RequestParam(value="action", required=true) String action) {

    if (action.equals("save")) {
        // do something here     
    }

    if (action.equals("cancel")) {
       // do another thing
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
```

This work good, but if I have more button, I must add more `if` statement to check the `action` string. Is there another way that I can create **one action** for **each button** in the form?

Comment: The Form action url is "@{/action/edit}" but in your controller "/edit",can you please tell me how you are linking your html & controller.

Comment: Pranesh Sahu, maybe a prefix `@RequestMapping(value="action")` on a controller class?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can create separate methods with different `@RequestMappings` using the params variable.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=save")
public ModelAndView save() {}


@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=cancel")
public ModelAndView cancel() {}
```

Answer (score 10):

this works in my problem.
use **th:formaction** on submit button this is work on how many you have submit button
and this is also usefull for give more links to one form with different submit button

```
<form action="#"  class="form" th:action="@{'/publish-post/'+${post.id}}" method="post">
<input class="savebtn" type="submit" value="Save" th:formaction="'/save-post/'+${post.id}">
<input class="publish" type="submit" value="Publish Article">
</form>
```

Comment: Very nice! Much cleaner than accepted answer, as it allows for well defined methods in Controller.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of an if-case you could have a switch case, should you not want to take in every option as a new request mapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/edit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView edit(@ModelAttribute SomeModel model, 
        @RequestParam(value="action", required=true) String action) {
    switch(action) {
        case "save":
            // do stuff
            break;
        case "cancel":
            // do stuff
            break;
        case "newthing":
            // do stuff
            break;
        default:
            // do stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Quite late to notice, but `break;` in `default` is heavily redundant (as the `switch` statement exits anyway).

Answer (score 3):

For multiple submit buttons, the below worked for me.
*Notice the: **th:formaction** in the cancel button.*

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/saveProducts}" th:object="${model}" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel" th:formaction="@{/cancelProducts}">CANCEL</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="save">SAVE</button>
</form>
```

For the controller:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/saveProducts", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute SomeModel model) {
      *//Do something*
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/cancelProducts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String cancel(@ModelAttribute SomeModel model) {
      *//Do something*

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
<div class="inner">
    <a href="#" th:onclick="|deleteContact(${c.cId})|" class="btn btn-danger btn-small">Delete</a>
<div class="inner">
    <form th:action="@{'/update-contact/'+${c.cId}}">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-small">Update</button>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here is output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbyNJ.png)

Answer (score -3):

You can know which submit button has been clicked and then act upon the button
Here is the code

```
String btnName = request.getParameter("action");

if(btnName.equals("save"))
    // you code....
else if(btnName.equals("cancel"))
    // you code....
```

Comment: To clarify the downvotes: Not only is this entirely different from the point of the question (looking for ways to avoid the `if` construct in this situation), but also, using `request.getParameter(...)` is way worse than wiring it directly to a method parameter using `@RequestParam` (as done in the question's code).