# Access value outside form using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I need to obtain vaulue of an input using thymeleaf and spring but haven't been able to do so. Since I need that value in a lot of the methods in the controller I can't put that input inside of one of the forms.

I tried to use javascript to pass on the value to a hidden input in the forms, however since I'm using th:each I'm only getting the value of the first input.

I also tried adding a string to the model and then trying to access that string with @ModelAttribute, but it didn't workout either.

This is the html:

```
<tr th:each="pro:${productos}">
    <td th:text="${pro.id}">id</td>
    <!-- More code here omitted for brevity-->
    <td>
        <div>
            <form th:action="@{|/actualizarMas/${pro.id}|}" method="post">
                <button type="submit" id="mas">+</button>
            </form>
            <form th:action="@{|/actualizarMenos/${pro.id}|}" method="post">
                <button type="submit" id="menos">-</button>                        
            </form>                   
            <input name="masomenos"/>

            <form th:action="@{|/${pro.id}|}" method="post">
                <button type="submit">Borrar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/actualizarMenos/{productosId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String eliminarUno(@PathVariable int productosId, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("masomenos") String masomenos) {

    //Code here using that string omitted for brevity        

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

I need to access the input with the name "masomenos", if that is posible, how could I do it?, if not, what options do I have? besides creating inputs inside all the forms.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look into [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401669/thymeleaf-multiple-submit-button-in-one-form), it may help you

Comment: <input name="masomenos" th:value="${value}"/>, can you try this? and it should be inside your <form> tags

Comment: Thank you both for the suggestions, actually the other post was quite helpful. I couldn't solve the problem per se but I was able to work around it.

Comment: Try to use this in the href `th:attr= "value=${id of the input tag}"` It Worked for me!!