# How to make HTML Button perform action in Java?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Basically I'm creating an upvote/downvote system, Now I've created two buttons in HTML :

```
<button type="button" name="upvote"></button>
<br>
<input type="number" th:value = "${commentValue}" disabled>
<br>
<button type="button" name="downvote"></button>
```

First button with name attribute - "upvote" and second with "downvote" , Now I want to catch a click on button and change the **commentValue** accordingly, **If user clicks upvote, comment value must incriment and on downvote it must decrement**

I found some topics that said to implement ActionListener, Create JButton objects and etc. but isn't there any simpler way ?

This is my code right now, The buttons do nothing. :

> Controller :

```
private int numberValue = 0;

@GetMapping("/check")
public String nuberCheck(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("commentValue", numberValue);

    return "numberCheck";
}

@PostMapping("/check")
public String upvote(Model model, @RequestParam String action){
    if (action == "upvote"){
        numberValue++;
        model.addAttribute("commentValue", numberValue);
    }else if (action == "downvote"){
        numberValue --;
        model.addAttribute("commentValue", numberValue);
    }
    return "numberCheck";

}
```

> numberCheck :

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/check}" method="post">
    <button type="button" name="action" th:value="upvote" th:text = "upvote"></button>
    <br>
    <input type="number" th:value = "${commentValue}" disabled>
    <br>
    <button type="button" name="action" th:value = "dowvnote" th:text = "dowvnote"></button>
</form>
```

**FIXED**

Change button types to "submit" and then in controller :

```
@PostMapping("/check")
public String check(Model model,@RequestParam String action) {

    System.out.println(action);

    if (action.equals("upvote")) {
        numberValue++;
        model.addAttribute("numberValue", numberValue);
    }

    if (action.equals("dowvnote")) {
        numberValue--;
        model.addAttribute("numberValue", numberValue);
    }
    return "numberCheck";
}
```

`@RequestParam String action` "action" is the name attribute of button and "save" and "cancel" are the "value" attributes :) hope it helps

Comment: I suppose this might be of help? At least for initial idea...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401669/thymeleaf-multiple-submit-button-in-one-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample:

HTML:

```
<form action="#" data-th-action="@{/action}" data-th-object="${model}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="upvote"></button>
    <button type="submit" name="downvote"></button>
</form>
```

Java:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/action", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView onClickAction() {}
```

Comment: in Java code , how to catch clicks on either upvote or downvote ?

Comment: @Tornike you could use params="action=upvote"

Ensure you have <button name="action" value="upvote">

Comment: Example like: @RequestMapping(value="/action", method=RequestMethod.POST, params="action=upvote")

Comment: please give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: So, I've changed my html to look like this -> 

       `<button type="button" name="action" value="upvote"></button>
        <br>
        <input type="number" th:value = "${commentValue}" disabled>
        <br>
        <button type="button" name="action" value = "dowvnote"></button>`

and controller : 

`@PostMapping(value = "/check", params = "action=upvote")
    public String upvote(Model model){
        numberValue++;
        model.addAttribute("commentValue", numberValue);
        return "numberCheck";
    }`

but pressing the button does nothing at all

Comment: hey you need a form action. where is "/check" initiated in your view ?

Comment: example: <form action="#" data-th-action="@{/check}" method="post">

Comment: Yes, I do have th:action="@{/check}", I'll update my question

Comment: @Tornike Ideally, this should work. Is there any exception logged ? You can enable debug logging on classes like these to help you diagnose routing issues:

<logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping" level="DEBUG" />
 <logger name="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping" level="DEBUG" />

Comment: Ok so I was able to do it. My buttons needed to be of type "submit" and not "button" :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following and implement in your code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#up").click(function(){
    var up = $.post("/upvote", {changeBy: 1}, function(dataBack){

        $("#upvote").text(dataBack);
    });

});
$("#down").click(function(){
    var down = $.post("/downvote", {changeBy: 1},
    function(dataBack){
        $("#downvote").text(dataBack);
    });

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that. first add jquery library in your html page and write function like below inside `script` tag

```js
function upVote(){
var counter= $('.comment').val();
counter++;
 $('.coment').val(counter);

}
function downVote(){
var counter= $('.comment').val();
counter--;
 $('.coment').val(counter);

}
```

```html
<button type="submit"  name="upvote" th:onclick="'upVote();'"></button>
<br>
<input type="number" class="comment"th:value = "${commentValue}" disabled>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="downvote" th:onclick="'upVote();'"></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one best way to solve this. When you click button trigger one event and at that event increase or decrease value. Use that value in an thymeleaf and pass it to the controller.