# Thymeleaf - multiple submit buttons in a form

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a form that currently only has a text input field. The user has 3 options regarding what to do with the input:

1. First, "Send" will take the input and save it (send) to another
   storage variable, and then display it below the input field as:
   "Current active value is: *input*".
2. The "Clear" button is supposed to clear this field, so that after
   pressing it the storage variable shows "null", like: "Current active
   value is: null".
3. The last one, "See Results" should take the input, compare it to a
   List of other values and then if there is a match open a new page
   and list results from a List.

Currently, only the Send button works fully. The "Clear" and "See Results" buttons are completely unresponsive, but appear on the page and can be clicked.

Any ideas how I can fix the 2 last buttons?

```
<body>
    <p>
        <a href='/NewTest'>New Test upload</a>
    </p>

    <div>
        <form th:action="@{/sendTest}" th:object="${Test}" method="post">
        <label for="name" id="name" >Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>

        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Send"/></form>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="Clear"/></form>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="See Results"/></form>
        <br>
    </div>

    <a> Current test for students: </a>
    <p th:text="${currentTest}" ></p>
    <div>
    <a>Available tests for students:</a>
    <th:block th:each="test : ${tests}">
        <tr>
            <td th:text="${test.getName()}">...</td>
            <td th:text="${test.getFile().getName()}">...</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</body>
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class TeacherController {

    TestController testcont = TestController.getInstance();

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/Teacher"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String teacher(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("Test", new Test());
        model.addAttribute("tests", testcont.showAllTests());
        model.addAttribute("currentTest", testcont.getActiveTest());


        return "Teacher";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sendTest"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String currentTestOptions(Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("Test", new Test());
        model.addAttribute("tests", testcont.showAllTests());
        model.addAttribute("currentTest", testcont.getActiveTest());


        return "Teacher";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sendTest"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, params="action=Send")
    public String sendTest(@Valid @ModelAttribute("test") Test test, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){


        for(Test i : testcont.showAllTests()){
            if(i.getName().equals(test.getName())) {
                testcont.SetActiveTest(i);
                model.addAttribute("currentTest", testcont.getActiveTest());
            }
        }

        return "sendTest";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sendTest"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, params="action=Clear")
    public String clearTest(){

        testcont.SetActiveTest(null);


        return "Teacher";

    }

    //***********Test Results************

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/TestResults"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String testResultsData(@Valid @ModelAttribute("test") Test test, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

        model.addAttribute("Students", testcont.showAllStudents());

        return "TestResults";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/sendTest"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, params="action=See Results")
    public String testResults(@Valid @ModelAttribute("test") Test test, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model){

        for(Test i : testcont.showAllTests()){
            if(i.getName().equals(test.getName())) {
                model.addAttribute("Answer", i.getStudentAnswer());
            }
        }

        return "TestResults";

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thymeleaf multiple submit button in one form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401669/thymeleaf-multiple-submit-button-in-one-form)

Comment: I saw that post, but I dont know how to adapt it to my situation. Anyways, I saw my form had end tags on the other input buttons, which prevented them from being linked to the form in the first place. Now they do some stuff at least.

Comment: If you still have some trouble with the bottom behaviour after you realised the wrong </form> tags, submit a new question with whatever the issue is :)

Comment: After some tinkering, it`s all working now! Sadly I had to walk away from my original design of using a dropdown menu, to a text field just to get things working. Now that this is working as intended I'll give the dropdown another go :)