# When thymeleaf form is submitted then handler in controller was not called

Tags: spring-boot, forms, controller, thymeleaf

As a model for my form I'm using

```
...
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class FormDto {
    private UUID id;
    private Set<UUID> items;
}
```

then I have this *checkbox_form*:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/roles/checkboxForm}" th:object="${dto}" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <input type="hidden" th:field="*{roleId}" th:value="*{roleId}" />

        <div class="row" th:each="user : ${users}">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{items}" th:value="${user.id}" th:id="${user.id}"/>
                <label th:for="${user.id}" th:text="${user.lastName}"></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr/>

        <button type="submit" name="action" value="save">add</button>
        <button type="submit" name="action" value="cancel">cancel</button>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and in Controller class I have two methods - GET and POST:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/list")
    public String getCheckboxForm(Model model) {

        var users = userService.getAllUsers();

        model.addAttribute("dto", new RoleAddUsersDto());
        model.addAttribute("users", users);

        return "checkbox_form";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/checkboxForm")
    public String handleCheckboxFormSubmit(@ModelAttribute("dto") RoleAddUsersDto dto,
                                           BindingResult bindingResult,
                                           Model model) {
        return "home";
    }
```

Here are raw form data from POST call:

```
id=0186d463-8661-4c25-bd5b-4fd75d3297ff&_items=on&_items=on&items=01d71d78-6697-41c1-a2ab-2c04d4dad576&_items=on&items=08d71d78-6697-41c1-a2ab-2c04d4dad576&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&_items=on&action=submit
```

but after form submit it never goes to *handleCheckboxFormSubmit* in controller. I can't find what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it never goes to handleCheckboxFormSubmit? If you submit the form and it takes you to home, then handleCheckboxFormSubmit is working as it's supposed to.

You're not doing anything in it so you wouldn't really know if it was called.

In handleCheckboxFormSubmit, add System.out.println("hello world"). Reload and hit submit the form again, and check your console output. You should see hello world there.

Another issue might be the multiple submit buttons. Read on th:formaction and checkout this answer by Parth Sarkheliya: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61013622/18902234

Comment: I'm sure because I have there breakpoint and it never stopped there. Also spring logged 404 - Resource not found. I never went to home page but showed me error page. and in logs I see `POST "/checkboxForm", parameters={id:[0186d463-8661-4c25-bd5b-4fd75d3297ff], _items:[on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on, on], items:[01d71d78-6697-41c1-a2ab-2c04d4dad576, 08d71d78-6697-41c1-a2ab-2c04d4dad576], action:[save]}`. A tried to add also `params="action=save"` to handler method but i didn't help.

Comment: @slon did you see the hello world printed in console? Can you post the entire controller class?

Comment: nope, any message in log.

Comment: I found reason :/ oh my... in `th:action="@{/roles/checkboxForm}"` I should have `th:action="@{/role/checkboxForm}"`.... so small change makes me crazy... Closing this queistion.... Thx